# Is there a quick way to change the tile layout for site contents to a list view (like it was in 2010/2007)?

Tags: 2013, layouts, tiles, site-contents

The tile layout is a new style that has been implemented in 2013 for most of the content being surfaced.

But it makes it difficult to quickly navigate when you have >25 lists and libraries. It would be much easier to have a list view (detailed view) like we had on 2010/2007. Any quick fix to achieve this and implement it across the site collections?

Answer (score 3):

You can use following JS for this:

```
function HideTiles() {
  $("#applist .ms-vl-apptile").css({ "display": "block" });
  $("#applist .ms-vl-apptile").css({ "min-height": "50px" });
  $("#applist .ms-vl-appinfo").css({ "min-height": "50px" });
  $("#applist .ms-vl-appinfo").css({ "width": "500px" });
  $("#applist .ms-vl-appimage").css({ "height": "50px" });
  $("#applist .ms-vl-appimage").css({ "width": "50px" });

  $("#applist #apptile-appadd .ms-vl-appimage").css({ "width": "96px" });

  $("#applist .ms-vl-appimage a.ms-storefront-appiconspan").css({ "height": "50px" });
  $("#applist .ms-vl-appimage a.ms-storefront-appiconspan").css({ "width": "50px" });
  $("#applist .ms-vl-appimage a.ms-storefront-appiconspan").css({ "line-height": "50px" });

  $("#applist img.ms-storefront-appiconimg").css({ "height": "50px" });
  $("#applist img.ms-storefront-appiconimg").css({ "line-height": "50px" });
 };
```

Then we need to actually make sure this gets executed. The problem here is that the Site Contents is rendered on-the-fly using JavaScript so we have to resort to a little Script on Demand to get this working.

```
$(function () {
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(HideTiles, “sp.ui.allapps.js”);
});
```

Then the only thing needed is to make sure this script gets dropped onto the page and this is done using a Custom Action (A delegate control could have been used with CSS style tags but that does not work in the Sandbox, i.e. Office 365)

```
<CustomAction
  ScriptSrc="~SiteCollection/_layouts/15/MJH.JSLink/MJH.AddCss.js"
  Location="ScriptLink"
  Sequence="20">
</CustomAction>
```

All Credit for this code goes to [Martin Hatch](https://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/changing-site-contents-to-list-view-css.html)

Comment: What does MJH.JSLink/MJH.AddCss.js refer to?

Comment: It refers your actual JS file in which you have saved above code. Its just an example name, you can use any name for JS.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out, but still looking for any easier implementations for the same.

Comment: Where do you add the Custom Action? There does not seem to be any ability to edit the viewlsts.aspx page to add any webpart...